# How to set date field to Today's Date in Wss 3.0 Custom list form programatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, date-time, wss

How can i pre-populate newitem.aspx form with today's date. When user adds new item i want to prepopulate  date field with todays date.

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcDateofInsp" runat="server" IsRequiredField="true" DateOnly="true"></SharePoint:DateTimeControl>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to set the column in the Sharepoint UI to use Today's Date as the default value for the column.

Comment: Pirate Eric, I created this list using visual studio, therefore changes doesn't get applied using SharePoint UI.

Comment: What Eric means is that you define you field like this:   <Field ...><Default>[today]</Default></Field>

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Jquery ? here is other link for List form customization which will open up all possibilities for you 
[enter link description here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/setting-form-field-visibility-and-editability-through-custom-list-field-iterators/)

Thanks 
Ronak

Comment: No i haven't yet tried Jquery, Do you anything useful in you hand?